# iOS 10, call directory extension not debugged

Tags: ios, xcode, nserror, cncontact, callkit

I am working on Call directory extension with callkit.

I selected Call directory extension for debug and when I run this target, no `NSLog` is shown.

How can I debug this extension?

ps : When I run this extension, `Debug -> Attach to process ->` no target is checked....

[image]

Comment: I face the same problem. Do you have some methods?

Answer (score 7):

Just use the menu point one above "Attach to Process by PID or Name" and use the name of the Callkit extension.

jvc

Answer (score 1):

Attaching the Xcode debugger to call kit extension is a little bit different from other extensions. When debugging it, although you see the extension "**Waiting to attach**" in debug navigator. Xcode doesn't attach it automatically like other extension! I am not sure if this is a Xcode bug.

So you have to attach the extension by yourself. I found there are 2 simple ways to do it,

1. Run your extension target, let you app load the extension, then you
   can see the extension process in "**Attach to Process**" menu,
   attach it. Then for **the 2nd time** you run into your extension
   Xcode will stop at your breakpoint.
2. Run your host app target, **Attach
   to Process by PID or Name**, use your **extension target name**. Then Xcode will stop at your breakpoint for the 1st time you run your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are debugging it with an iPad without SIM card? Try with an iPhone instead.